# Is there a grammar pattern like 〜うち + Noun?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Context: https://komachi.yomiuri.co.jp/t/2019/0805/908840.htm?g=02

> **1か月のうち仕事**？とよばれるものはトータルで3時間もないと思います。ボタン押すだけです。夕方、鬱屈として叫びだしたくなります。

I think the phrase in bold means "one month's work". What kind of うち is this ? I could not find any grammar pattern associated with うち+Noun.

Comment: You have parsed the sentence incorrectly. 1か月のうち仕事と呼ばれるもの = "In an (arbitrary) month, something that can be called work"

Comment: I just checked out the question linked for duplicate. With your comment and the answer to that question, うち makes much more sense now. Thank you !